# The purpose of sub-shell invocation (via `backticks`) in Automake macros for C and C++ compilation

Tags: c, shell, sh, gnu-make, automake

Certain C and C++ IDEs support *GNU Make* based projects by parsing the output of `make`. So they basically run `make -wnk`, extract the compiler invocations (`gcc -c -o file.o file.c`) as well as `Entering directory ...` / `Leaving directory ...` messages from said log and build the project model based on this. One notable example of such an IDE is [*NetBeans*](https://netbeans.org/), but of course there're others.

Now, whenever a project uses both `autoconf` and `automake`, the exact command line looks like this (taken from [*strace*](https://strace.io/) source code):

```sh
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I./linux/x86_64 -I./linux/x86_64 -I./linux -I./linux -I. -I.     -DIN_MPERS -DMPERS_IS_mx32 -I./mpers-mx32  -Wall -Wempty-body -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Woverride-init -Wsign-compare -Wtype-limits -Wwrite-strings -Werror   -g -O2 -MT libmpers_mx32_a-v4l2.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmpers_mx32_a-v4l2.Tpo -c -o libmpers_mx32_a-v4l2.o `test -f 'v4l2.c' || echo './'`v4l2.c
```

So each source file being compiled is referenced on the command line as

```sh
`test -f 'file.c' || echo './'`file.c
```

meaning whenever the file is **present** in the current directory (or is a symlink to a regular file), it gets compiled as

```
gcc -c file.c
```

while a **nonexistent** file gets instead compiled as

```
gcc -c ./file.c
```

I feel this *may* have something to do with [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html) but can't properly explain it. The reason I'm asking the question is that *NetBeans* (as well as some other similar tools) fails to parse such a command line (with backticks and a sub-shell invocation on it) and can't build a proper project model for `automake`-based projects.

Digging a bit deeper, I found that such shell constructs are not present in `Makefile.am` files in the first place -- only in `Makefile.in`'s `automake` generates. Now, looking at `/usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am` (the exact path may vary), here're the definitions of the original macros:

```
?!GENERIC?      %VERBOSE%%COMPILE% -MT %OBJ% -MD -MP -MF %DEPBASE%.Tpo %-c% -o %OBJ% %SOURCEFLAG%`test -f '%SOURCE%' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`%SOURCE%
?-o?    %VERBOSE-NODEP%%COMPILE% %-c% %-o% %OBJ% %SOURCEFLAG%`test -f '%SOURCE%' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`%SOURCE%
?!-o?   %VERBOSE-NODEP%%COMPILE% %-c% %SOURCEFLAG%`test -f '%SOURCE%' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`%SOURCE%
?!GENERIC?      %VERBOSE%%LTCOMPILE% -MT %LTOBJ% -MD -MP -MF %DEPBASE%.Tpo %-c% -o %LTOBJ% %SOURCEFLAG%`test -f '%SOURCE%' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`%SOURCE%
?!GENERIC?      %VERBOSE-NODEP%%LTCOMPILE% %-c% -o %LTOBJ% %SOURCEFLAG%`test -f '%SOURCE%' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`%SOURCE%
```

## Questions

1. Can you explain the purpose of such sub-shell invocations?
2. Can whatever is in-between the backticks be safely dropped when building the project model, or are there any corner cases?

Comment: Perhaps it comes into play when the project is built in a separate directory from where the source is. Try running `configure` from outside the source tree. For example, create a separate build area and run `mkdir build; cd build; ../configure` instead of the usual `./configure`.

Comment: It's probably a futile hope to ask any tool to understand automake's output. There's a mountain of auto-generated junk and compatibility shims in `Makefile` and `Makefile.in`. As a human being I only deal with the source files: `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`.

Comment: You're right. For _in-tree_ builds, the `fchownat.c` file, for example, is compiled as ``$(test -f 'fchownat.c' || echo './')fchownat.c`` which just evaluates to `fchownat.c`, while for the _out-of-tree_ build the same file is now compiled as `$(test -f 'fchownat.c' || echo '../strace/')fchownat.c` which now evaluates to `../strace/fchownat.c`.

Comment: What John said. 20 years ago, my job revolved around autoconf and automake (porting and packaging userland for an embedded Linux distro). I would _never_ try to write a program that executes their output without a compliant shell; better (albeit not much) to do your own processing of its input, if one really must do something other than execute it as-designed. NetBeans is trying to do things bass-ackwards here.

Comment: autoconf tries hard to be able to build ridiculously backwards-compatible output. That means the tools you need (including POSIX-compliant shells -- though autoconf can also build output for heirloom Bourne) are available everywhere, Windows included. I can't think of a single good reason why they wouldn't use a real shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can. Autoconf is able to compile on a SunOS aka Solaris which contains tools originated from 1970s without major improvements.

Comment: There's more functionality in this check. A file can be generated locally in the build tree and it will override the one existing in the source tree. Looking at @Bass example, if `fchownat.c` was generated in the build tree, this one would be compiled instead of `../strace/fchownat.c`.

Comment: @raspy, I think we're in violent agreement here. SunOS `/bin/sh` is heirloom Bourne, which I just said in my last comment that Autoconf supports. By "real shell", I didn't mean specifically a POSIX-compliant shell; I meant *a real shell*, as opposed to some Java code that tries to parse a subset of shell syntax without actually being a shell.